# Locking a database row in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using Entity framework 3.5

I need to edit a database row, and I want to ensure that no other process edits this row once I start editing it.

How do I achieve this in Entity Framework 3.5?

I am looking to lock a specific row, not an entire table.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by implementing **pessimistic concurrency.**

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/continuing-with-ef/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-web-application) to learn more about concurrency in EF. There are also some tutorials on the same website about how to implement different methods for handling concurrency.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think Its by default lock the whole table?

Comment: I think so to, so one would have to handle locks on individual rows specially.

Comment: How do I lock an individual row? I would not want to lock the whole table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scope like this:

```
var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions
{
    IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable,
    Timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue
};

using (var scope = new TransactionScope(
        TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions))
{
    // Your code
}
```